# Episerver unable to see home page without login

Tags: episerver

I have an Episerver Application. But I am unable to access any page of it. As this is redirecting me to /util/login.aspx page all time and I do not have the Login credentials with me this time.

Is there any way to skip that authentication or fake login using any other technique.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless if you have an SQL provider for authentication the username and password will come from the domain or local computer.

If you are running an epi site locally you typically configure it to use the login credentials (i.e. windows role and membership) from your local computer.

Read more at https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/security/Authentication-and-authorization/

Answer (score 0):

Does the "**Everyone**" user group have `Read` permission for the pages?

If you're running the site locally, you can skip authentication altogether by modifying the applicable `<location />` element(s) in web.config, allowing you into admin mode to validate permissions.